# Difference between Typed and Untyped lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I would ask what's the difference between this two forms of lazy load modules in Angular:

```
    {
        path:'',
        loadChildren: './mymodule.module#MyModule'
    }
```

And:

```
    {
        path:'',
        loadChildren: () => MyModuleModule
    }
```

I don't know if these are two ways to do the same thing or if there is any performance or behavior difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax:

```
{
    path:'',
    loadChildren: () => MyModuleModule
}
```

Does *not* result in a lazy loaded module. It directly references `MyModuleModule`, so when the Angular CLI bundles the packages, it will bundle the `MyModuleModule` with whatever module this code is in.

Use this syntax if you need to specifically load a feature module's child routes in a specific location in your route hierarchy.

But NOTE: I *used* to cover this in one of my "Angular Routing" talks I was doing at conferences. One of the members of the Angular team suggested I *stop* covering it because the lazy loaded syntax should be used instead in most all cases.

This syntax:

```
{
    path:'',
    loadChildren: './mymodule.module#MyModule'
}
```

*Does* result in a lazy loaded module. The module name is defined within a string, so it has no direct reference and is not bundled with the module it's defined in.